# Can joomla be configured to browser through a proxy server?

Tags: proxy, joomla

In wordpress there are some simple variables that can be set to make the configuration of a navigation proxy server trivial.

```
var $proxy_host = ""; // proxy host to use
var $proxy_port = ""; // proxy port to use
var $proxy_user = ""; // proxy user to use
var $proxy_pass = ""; // proxy password to use
```

Are there any equivalents to accomplish the same for joomla?
I've been searching on internet and couldn't find anything.

For the original wordpress source see [here](http://wpengineer.com/1227/wordpress-proxysupport/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm updating the question with a definitive answer, as the time passed the proxy feature was integrated into joomla, and it's now present on Joomla 3.3 (you just have to check it in general configuration settings), the ticket with the discussion can be found [here](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=30941)

So basically, as of joomla 3.3 **proxy is working**

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using this to set the proxy with my servers, it works on everythin except for joomla, so there's probably something being force in joomla's side.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-default.php